# Moving TFS working folder to network share

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Our IT folks are telling us (the dev group) we shall not have ANY files stored on our local hard drives, including our TFS working folders. This is ridiculous for a variety of reasons but until I'm convinced it's a good idea, I'll play along and when no one is looking make a local working folder.

Does anyone does have their working folder on a network share? How well does it work? Each developer would have their own folder in the share but it would be on the network. My main concerns are performance and we would need to be connected at all times in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

On a TFS point of view it's working without issue, but stay away from the Local Workspace of TFS/VS11.

I strongly feel for you on the compiling point of view, compiling a solution stored over the network is absolutely a disaster in term of performances.

You did not mention it but I assume your Network Share uses a Network Drive.

Btw, can I know why these guys don't want you to store files locally ?

Comment: The "why" is a very good question. We have a black & white organizational policy that mandates no files allowed to be stored locally. We have 10K+ employees but < 10 developers and if no one else has a problem, how could the devs?

Comment: So let's hope you have lots of fiber channel NAS! :)

Comment: And don't use resharper! - This approach takes the whole disk i/o problem to a whole new level :D

Answer (score -1):

While it's not something I would typically recommend, if that is the policy and you have to adhere to it, it might be worthwhile to consider simply having server-side development VM's that your devs RDP into.  I've seen companies do this before, and the big downside is that if your not connected to the network you can't do anything.

There are some upsides too though.  Being able to easily increase resources (RAM, disk space, CPU, etc) because of the virtualization infrastructure.  If somebodies laptop dies they are not out of comission, just find a loaner machine and RDP into their VM and they're up and running.  If somebody leaves, you have a copy of their entire working machine that you can give to their replacement.  All machines can be easily backed up. Etc.  Compiling, and working within VS in general should be much faster too than trying to work with a local Visual Studio reading/writing to a network drive.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you wouldn't recommend it?  I am looking at a similar situation, and am trying to convince our lead programmer (old school mainframer) why developers should have a local development environment.

Comment: Visual Studio does a lot of disk access to the workspace files.  If they are on a network share there will be really high latency that will significantly degrade VS performance.